# how to get only selected table from stored procedures?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a stored Procedure like the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spConfiguration_test]
@ID int
AS
select empid,name from employee;
select * from address;
```

I wanted to call this stored procedure from jpa.So I did like this

**DAOcode**

```
public List test()
{
    String execProce="exec spConfiguration_test 1";
    System.out.println(execProce);
    Query query = entityManagerUtil.entityManager.createNativeQuery(execProce);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**service class Code**

```
List test=serviceDaoImpl.test();
```

when I debug this then List(test) size is showing 1 and when I run it then it gives me only the records of 1st table(select empid,name from employee;)

But I want the details of 2nd table when the stored procedure is executed.

Can any one guide me please?

Comment: what JPA implementation? what version of JPA ?

Comment: @NeilStockton I am using hibernate-jpa-2.0-api

Comment: in which case your only option is split your stored proc up into 2 ... you can only get multiple result sets from a stored proc with JPA 2.1

Comment: @NeilStockton do you want me to upgrade JPA to 2.1?

Comment: @NeilStockton are you sure if I upgrade to JPA 2,1 then I will get List size as 2 and if there are n number of select queries then I will get list size as n?

Comment: JPA 2.1 provides a way of executing StoredProcedures as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/stored_procedures.html where you call getResultList once for each resultSet, so in your case you call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you merge the two queries into one. Then everything must work.

Example:

```
SELECT e.empid
      ,e.name
      ,a.*
  FROM employee e
      ,address a
 WHERE e.empid = a.empid;
```

Comment: I have not posted my orginal code,so your way wont work